# How Embed a HTML form with additional element on condition using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>form</title>
<link href="MyStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body class="form">
<h1>Application Form</h1>


<form class="fdmain" method="post" id="form2" name="form2" action=>
  <p>
    <label for="textfield">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="stdname" id="tfname">


  </p>
  <p>Father Name:
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="tffathername">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="tel">Tel:</label>
    <input type="tel" name="tel" id="tel">
  </p>
  <p>Select Application Type:
      <select name="appselect" id="appselect" onchange="myfunc()">
      <option value="" selected>Select Here </option>
      <option value="Course_Application">Course Application</option>
      <option value="Acc_State">Statement of Account</option>
      <option value="Invite">Invitation</option>
      <option value="Complain_Application">Complain</option>
      <option value="SA_Applications">Student Affair Application</option>
    </select>
    </p>

     <script type="application/javascript">
    function myfunc(){
        var Appread = document.forms[0].appselect.value;
        if(Appread.localeCompare("Course_Application")==0)
        {
            document.write( "<p>");
            document.write("<label>");
            document.write("<input type='radio' class='CARadio' name='CAType' value='drop' id='CAType_0'>");
            document.write("Drop</label>");
            document.write("<br>");
            document.write("<label>");
            document.write("<input type='radio' class='CARadio' name='CAType' value='withdraw' id='CAType_1'>");
            document.write("Withdraw</label>");
            document.write("<br>");
            document.write("<label>");
            document.write("<input type='radio' class='CARadio' name='CAType' value='other' id='CAType_2'>");
            document.write("Other</label>");
            document.write("<br>");
            document.write("</p>");
            document.write("</p>");
            document.write("<p>If Other Please Specify:</p>");
            document.write("<p>");
            document.write("<textarea name='txfdCApp' id='txtCAP'></textarea>");
            document.write("</p>");
            }

    }
    </script>



  <p>Application Details:</p>
  <p>
    <textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" rows="10" cols="30" ></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit2" formmethod="POST" value="Submit">
  </p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>

</form>



</body>
</html>
```

I have only made the code for the first selection option. But the part of the code I have written in myfunc opens in another window. I want to code in a way that for every particular option the additional code opens on the same form after the end of select tag  and before the additional information tag.

What am I doing wrong.

Comment: Is it acceptable to have these extra fields hidden, and then simply show them when required?

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you have an issue with code, try to post your question in the following structure: What you are trying to do - what you've tried - what doesn't work and how it doesn't work. It helps us help you!

Comment: And I also think having a hidden form and just making it visible would be much simpler.

Comment: Hidden form? i don't understand?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would to suggest to place all your conditionally required fields into a `div`. Then use JavaScript to determine whether to show the `div` or not. This eliminates the needs to create HTML nodes manually, which can be messy.

You also need to consider the implications if the user picks the same option in the select list multiple times... it will keep adding nodes, which is bad.

Relevant code snippet:

```
    <div id='extra_questions' style='display: none; background-color: #0094ff;'>
        <!-- add radio buttons or whatever here -->
        Question #1<br />
        Question #2<br />
        Etc.<br />
    </div>

    <script type="application/javascript">
        function myfunc() {
            var Appread = document.forms[0].appselect.value;
            if (Appread.localeCompare("Course_Application") == 0) {
                document.getElementById('extra_questions').style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                document.getElementById('extra_questions').style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: let me try i will get back to you

Comment: Yes! It worked perfectly well and suffice enough for my purpose. Thanks

Comment: Excellent, could you flag this as the answer to the question?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it backwards. :-)

You are writing code with document.write. Where do you think this code goes to?

(Remember that the javascript is executed when an option changes in your SELECT.)

End of document? (Which already had its  tags I presume)

The right way to add "live" elements to your page is by creating new DOM elements.

It might seem daunting in the beginning, but give it a shot.

I recommend starting here (and avoid w3schools):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

After the `</select>` tag, add this.

```
<option value="SA_Applications">Student Affair Application</option>
</select>
</p>
<div id="ApplicationTypeResult"></div>
```

Then, save this as testresult.html in the same folder.

```
<p><label><input type='radio' class='CARadio' name='CAType' value='drop' id='CAType_0'>Drop</label><br>
<label><input type='radio' class='CARadio' name='CAType' value='withdraw' id='CAType_1'>Withdraw</label><br>
<label><input type='radio' class='CARadio' name='CAType'>Other</label><br></p>
<p>If Other Please Specify:</p>
<p><textarea name='txfdCApp' id='txtCAP'></textarea></p>
```

And try this.

```
function myfunc() {
    var Appread = document.forms[0].appselect.value;
    if(Appread.localeCompare("Course_Application")==0) {
        document.getElementById("ApplicationTypeResult").innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="testresult.html"></object>';
}
```

It will be easier if you use jquery by

```
function myfunc() {
    var Appread = document.forms[0].appselect.value;
    if(Appread.localeCompare("Course_Application")==0) {
       $("#ApplicationTypeResult").load("testresult.html");
}
```

Hope this helps, please change your div id name to whatever you might need and note the pathname to whereever you might save the file.

Expected behaviour will be this, (just plain).

[image: before select]

[image: After select]

Comment: If you could please specify. I tried but it's not working. It's giving me an error.

Comment: Cool, also note u can create more argument and fetch whatever result u want from the dropdown list as selection.